# Full calendar styling not showing in website

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

Just trying to pop a basic config of fullcalendar into my website, and for some reason the CSS isn't working. I've been playing around with the order and versions of the different links but am having no luck. Here's my code:

```
<head>
  <div id="calendar1"></div>
  <script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.7.1/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.7.1/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.7.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <style><link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.1/fullcalendar.min.css'/></style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: have a look my answer in bellow

Comment: you can put your ``<script>`` to ``<body>``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<style>` tag!
Change

```
<style><link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.1/fullcalendar.min.css'/></style>
```

to

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.1/fullcalendar.min.css'>
```

See this link for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Oh wow, yep that was it, thank you! I think I had been playing with adding/removing with different cdnjs combinations because I wasn't sure if it was the link or the tag. Great to know for future reference

Comment: I am happy that I could help! Thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistake on your code(unwanted `<style>` tag), I have corrected in below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.7.1/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.7.1/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.7.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.1/fullcalendar.min.css'/></style>
  
<div id="calendar1"></div>
```